# CryptoSLAX with Qualcomm Atheros Killer E2200

Tags: msi

As many people, I am a newbie on Linux but found CryptoSLAX an amazing tool for cryptomining.

I am currently trying to make my ethernet cards from my mobo MSI Z87G45 Gaming to work on CryptoSLAX, but because I am very, very stupid on Linux, I would like to perhaps have a little help from one of the enlightening Linux guys to get me to make this card to work.
The card is a Qualcomm Atheros Bigfoot Killer E2200.

So, what to do?

many thanks

SODERI

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no linux drivers for the Bigfoot Networks onboard Ethernet (Killer Series).

I take it you have a Gigabyte G1 board, probably LGA1366?

I have a G1.Guerrilla that I tried to use before.

It will not work.

Head on over to your local computer shop and pick up a cheap PCI ethernet card.

That's the only option you have.